# Need an ideal opensource 3D engine for building Golf simulation game

Tags: opengl

I'm looking for a open-source 3D graphics and physics engine specialized in golf simulation.

The preferred engine would be have short learning curve, supports Windows platform and Java or C++ and Lua/Python support for scripting, also prefer something like outdoor golf plane scene with weather system support, I'm new to this area and would love to hear all of your advice.

I'm just come from stackoverflow site, @mikera there recommends jMonkeyEngine, it sounds a fit, but I'm not sure if there's other ideal candidate engine?

Answer (score 4):

Try Ogre3D as a graphics engine and [bullet](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreBullet) as a physics engine.